# How to add address to users with Google map and jt-rails-address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new on rails. I work on a project, and I try to add physical address to my users. I want that the address can be help-complete with Google map for later exploitation. I find the [jt-rails-address](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/jt-rails-address) which look like perfect for my project. But I can't implement it. I need complete address (street, zip code, city & country).

add_address_to_users.rb :

```
class AddAddressToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
  add_column :users, :address, :address
 end
end
```

form edit.html.erb :

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for (@user), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :phone, "Téléphone :" %>
  <%= f.phone_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :address, "Addresse :" %>
  <div class="jt-address-autocomplete">
    <!-- This field is used to search the address on Google Maps -->
    <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'jt-address-search' %>

    <!-- All fields are hidden because the javascript will set their value automatically -->
    <% for attr in JT::Rails::Address.fields %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "address_#{street}", class: "jt-address-field-#{street}" %>
    <% end %>

    <% for attr in JT::Rails::Address.fields %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "address_#{zip_code}", class: "jt-address-field-#{zip_code}" %>
    <% end %>

    <% for attr in JT::Rails::Address.fields %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "address_#{city}", class: "jt-address-field-#{city}" %>
    <% end %>


    <% for attr in JT::Rails::Address.fields %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "address_#{country}", class: "jt-address-field-#{country}" %>
    <% end %>

  </div>

    <%= f.submit "Enregistrer les changements", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

application.js :

```
// This function is call when Google Maps is loaded
window.googleMapInitialize = function(){

// Simple usage
$('.jt-address-autocomplete').jt_address();

 };
```

I have already put :address in my user_params in the users controller and   has_address :address in the user model
I also have put my Google Api.

My actual error:

> undefined local variable or method `street' for #<#Class:0x00007fe91ec7f768:0x00007fe91dfaefc0>

Thanks in advance for your help.

> No more error but a bug, maybe because of Google Map, I don't know how
> to resolve it, I can't write the address and there is an error message:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6WJP.png)

Here the code of the inspector:

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add fields like in documentation or scope them using `select`, now you have code that will create  duplicated hidden fields.

You should check from rails console that method address is available on `User` instance of model.` Maybe you forgot to run migration or didn't restart server after installing this gem as this is js gem and will need restart.

Hope this answers your questions. Add comment to this answer if problem is still there.

Comment: I put the fields like the documentation : '        <!-- All fields are hidden because the javascript will set their value automatically -->
        <% for attr in JT::Rails::Address.fields %>
          <%= f.hidden_field "address_#{attr}", class: "jt-address-field-#{attr}" %>
        <% end %>' and I restart the server but it put a new error message : undefined method `address_formatted_address' for #<User:0x00007fbad57c03e8>
Did you mean?  address_before_last_save

Comment: https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/jt-rails-address/issues/5 There is a problem with migration in this gem

Comment: Thanks, it works, no more error, but a bug : I can't write the address : See on my post up

Comment: I would seriously reconsider dumping this gem, it below 20 stars, it’s not reliable enough

Comment: Do you know another gem to do that ?

Comment: Use geocoder with some js plugin. You need to code that, sometimes there isn’t gem for everything and gems can only help to some extent